# Modal and Contact form in Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I'm busy creating a website. I was busy setting the URL's of the Navbar and  I came across a conundrum

Currently, I have a contact form at the bottom of my Index page. the contact form uses the Include method from Django to render the parts of the Index page. So to the short end of it is that the Contact form doesn't have a view or URL

So I was wondering if there is a way to set the Contact form by Id or class in my Navbar so when the user is on the Index page it slides down to the contact form and on other pages, it opens a modal containing the from.

I would like to avoid having the modal pop up on the Index page because then it makes the contact form at the bottom kind of redundant.

If this is not possible then I think I might just remove the contact form at the bottom and just use a modal site wide.

Need some advice if this is possible or other approaches would be welcomed

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Javascript but it felt too clunky so I removed the form at the bottom in the footer section and added a modal instead.